# Sweave outputing ascii unicode

Tags: unicode, sweave

i have a file .Rnw with non unicode characters in utf8.
When I compile with `Sweave(file, encoding="UTF-8")`, the .tex output has the unicode characters in the form `<U+00F3>`.

How can I get the .tex output in utf8?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it was happening is that I was compiling from php executing bash script, so I didn't have the LANG environment variable set. In the script I set the variable `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, and R compiles good.